# Is the Dynamics CRM 2013 Xrm.Internal.openDialog method supported on the ipad?

Tags: ipad, modal-dialog, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I can't see any information online about this but I'm trying to get a dialog working with CRM 2013. It works fine on the web version and Outlook client, but I'm getting an error on the iPad app.
Does anyone know if the following is supported on the iPad or if not a good alternative?

```
var webresourceurl = "/WebResources/Org_/HTML/MyDialog.html?Data=somedata";
var DialogOptions = new Xrm.DialogOptions(); 
DialogOptions.width = 500;
DialogOptions.height = 300;
Xrm.Internal.openDialog(webresourceurl , DialogOptions, null, null, CallbackFunction);

function CallbackFunction(returnValue){ 
 alert(returnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you know that the use of `Xrm.Internal` namespace is not supported.

In your scenario maybe you can use the supported `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenWebResource

but if you need a return value, maybe it's better to use the standard javascript `window.showModalDialog`.

My best guess is that CRM maps the `Xrm.Internal.openDialog` to the `window.showModalDialog` function, but in the latest days this function has issues with Google Chrome ([details here](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/the-browser-compatibility-cake-is-lie.html)).

Replying to your main question (the support inside the iPad application) the answer is no, there isn't a way to open a dialog inside the mobile app, this is by design (avoiding popups and create a "flat" interface)

Comment: I am trying to find a good replacement for openModalDialog that will work cross browser. It doesn't seem there is anything out there that you can pass arguments into that is fully supported by CRM. Any ideas?

Comment: As best I can tell, "openWebResource", despite allowing for params of height and width, always opens in a new tab. I can't get it to open in a new window (modal or non-modal). I may be missing something, but it seems like height and width are ignored.